# Different types of listings in Sobi2

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I am working on a listing website using Sobi2. I need to list some items under 'Buy' and others under 'Hire'. I have a check box in the Sobi 2 add entry form to select under which the item has to be displayed. But how can I realize this..? I mean how can I show the items for which the user has Buy under a 'Buy' menu..? I have different categories and these categories are same for the Buy and Hire. It is like I have two types of listings and the parameters for both are same. Please advise me how can I realize it in Sobi2...?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to clone the SOBI2 Extension and have 2 installations of it.

This process is a little involved but there is great documentation of how to do it [HERE](http://www.sigsiu.net/forum/community-board-for-tips-tricks/bash-script-to-clone-sobi2-and-plugins-%28cloning-tool%29/130/).

I had to do something similar on a site once and cloning the installation was great - then I didn't have any worry of anything getting crossed up.  It sounds like this is what you'll need since they're 'identical' but do 2 vastly different things.

Comment: Thanks Hanny. This seems to be helpful. I will give a try. thanks again.

Comment: NP Alwin.  If this solves your issue please make sure to flag my answer as the correct one so others know this has been solved and is correct!

Comment: Actually I have another problem. I only have cPanel hosting and so I planned to execute the script as a cron job. But I think we need to provide the name for new clone in the process. Is there any workaround for this.. ?

Comment: Well, if you follow those instructions, basically you can do the cloning all locally on any windows machine (no need to mess with cpanel or cron jobs) - that basically makes the clone a 'new extension' that needs to be installed the same way you installed the first version of Sobi2.

Comment: Thanks Hanny..Actually I have done it in my Ubuntu and installed successfully. Thanks again..otherwise I would have ended up in some messed up code. :)

Comment: How about cloning a plugin for installing it to sobi2 clone...? I have cloned the Sobi2 and installed it in the name of market place. Now need to clone the download,image gallery and ,media gallery plugins. I have tried it with the tool. But is resulting  in "Error: Could not parse XML file. Installation aborted (90) " error. Please let me know how we can install plugins.

Comment: Actually I need some urgent help . I have done the cloning and all and displaying the categories as a drop down menu. Now upon adding the entry it is showing missing category error and it is not added. Please help me it is very urgent.

Comment: I don't think you need to clone the plugins and such that you install (I could be wrong, it's been a while since I've done it) - because those plugins get installed in each version of your sobi2 and are kept separate by Sobi2 - no need to clone them.  As far as the error your experiencing - it sounds like some possible setup issue with Sobi2;  I would need more details I think to even make a guess.  What else is going on with it?  Does the category exist?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who sees this question in the future the preferred method now would probably be to use SobiPro instead (still a free component despite the 'pro' name).  This, amongst other things allows you to run multiple distinct directories within the one component, without the rigmarole of cloning.

Comment: Thanks Dean. But actually I have installed and running sobi2 I need to continue with it at least for now. Helpful if you can give some information abut how to clone and install plugins.